# Show image from database using filepath asp.net and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to show image on the label retrieved from the database. 
My front end code is

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="150px" Width="120px" />
```

where as my backend code is:

```
  string query = "select quantity, name, price, description, type, Catagory, FilePath from product where p_id ='" + IdList.SelectedValue + "'  ";
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if(rdr.HasRows)
            {
                while (rdr.Read())
                {  string filename1 = rdr.GetString(6);
                    Image1.ImageUrl="C:\\Users\\Fatima\\Downloads\\db-final-project\\db final project\\db final project\\UploadedImages\\"+filename1; }
```

kindly help me in displaying my image in label in the web form

Comment: what is the value of filename1 ?

Comment: its the name of image retrieved from  database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"**C:\Users\Fatima\Downloads\db-final-project\db final project\db final project\UploadedImages\**" is not a valid URL. 
Image1.ImageUrl expects a URL, like "http://www.SomeSite.com/someImage.jpg", and not a local directory on your hard-drive.

Put those pictures in your database (there should be a table column of type 'image' which can store images) or better yet - add it as an asset to your project and link to its relative path (e.g., the path in which your site/application resides in, without the domain name).

You can see a valid usage of Image.ImageUrl in here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.image.imageurl.aspx